# How can I fill a matplotlib grid?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to render a ggplot2 style filled grid, a la [image: this]
<sub>(source: [had.co.nz](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/graphics/b1d84765165d97b51c63c292bc638f0b.png))</sub>

I haven't been able to find any online resources that deal with styling the grid in such a way. Do I have to resort to doing something like plotting my own rectangular patches?

Edit: after trying Chris' solution, I have written a script to help make matplotlib graphs look like ggplot2 if anyone is interested.

http://messymind.net/making-matplotlib-look-like-ggplot/

Comment: With fill do you mean the background colour?

Comment: +1 for contributing back your solution.

Comment: are you familiar with https://github.com/yhat/ggplot ?

Comment: @tcaswell that module looks like a great option for some. I personally think R/ggplot syntax is not great and prefer to use matplotlib as usual. Obviously this is personal preference

Comment: you might also be interested in the `style` module which is on master (and will be in 1.4) which allows better control of rcparams.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code uses [`matplotlib.pyplot.grid`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.grid) to turn on a grid and set the grid properties (line colour, style and width) and then uses `plt.gca().patch.set_facecolor('0.8')` to change the axes color (I'm not sure if there is, but there must be convenience function to do this). The argument to `patch.set_facecolor` is any [matplotlib colour](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/colors_api.html).

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = numpy.random.rand(10)
x = numpy.random.rand(10)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')

plt.grid(True, color='w', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
plt.gca().patch.set_facecolor('0.8')

plt.show()
```

The result is

[image: Figure generated by the code above]

Comment: Brilliant. I had little expectation that I'll get an answer, much less such a simple one. I'll expand on this and see if I can get it into the gallery.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to update the grid background for a single chart, you can just do:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_facecolor('#EBEBEB')
# Plot something..
```

But if you want full ggplot styles for all your charts, Matplotlib comes with a `ggplot` theme so the easiest way to do this is to enable that:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

Seaborn also has a similar theme:

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
```

Lastly, you can also set the `rcParams` manually if you'd prefer:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator
import numpy as np

# This isn't a full styling but gets you most of the way.
ggplot_styles = {
    'axes.edgecolor': 'white',
    'axes.facecolor': 'EBEBEB',
    'axes.grid': True,
    'axes.grid.which': 'both',
    'axes.spines.left': False,
    'axes.spines.right': False,
    'axes.spines.top': False,
    'axes.spines.bottom': False,
    'font.size': 12,
    'grid.color': 'white',
    'grid.linewidth': '1.4',
    'xtick.color': '555555',
    'xtick.major.bottom': True,
    'xtick.minor.bottom': False,
    'ytick.color': '555555',
    'ytick.major.left': True,
    'ytick.minor.left': False,
}

plt.rcParams.update(ggplot_styles)

# Plot an example chart.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
x = np.linspace(0, 14, 100)
for i in range(1, 7):
    ax.plot(x, np.sin(x + i * .5) * (7 - i))

# Set minor ticks/gridline cadence.
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))

# Turn minor gridlines on and make them thinner.
ax.grid(which='minor', linewidth=0.5)
```

[image: matplotlib plot with ggplot style]